# Retrieving maven-metadata.xml for one package and from one specific repostiory

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-metadata

Maven writes metadata about package versioning and so on to files called maven-metadata*.xml I have to determine the root cause of some version changes in such a metadata file, because it seems to break a build of mine.

Is there a command line call with which I can download this file to my local computer for a specific package and for a specific Nexus repository? Or is there another way to find out, how a maven repository sets these version information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple solution (I should have seen it in the first place):

Nexus stores the maven-metadata.xml from itself and the different remote repositories under

```
/<nexus_install_dir>/storage/<repo_name>/<packae_and_artifact_id>/maven-metadata.xml
```